# how can i enter data in text fields of an existing windows based application using Autoit?

Tags: autoit

I am trying to automate an existing windows based application designed by my organisation using AutoIt.

I am able to launch the application, but i am not able to proceed further.

I want to recognize to objects used on the window and use them to add text to fields, read text from fields, click on buttons, etc.

Not sure if AutoIt supports that or not. But if yes, can you please help me with the same. And if not, what tool i should use to do the same.

its a small organisation, hence they do not very keen to spend money on automation tools.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Autoit Window Info (comes with the installation). This tool helps you to identify the controls and to get the handles to address those controls. Then use Control... commands to interact.

Comment: @TestIT, try to be more specific on what your problem is. Helping you to learn a who programming language, isn't what this site is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the AutoIT info tool that comes with autoit. Get the handles of the controls and then you can do what you want to do

Example:

```
ControlSetText - set the text of the control
ControlGetText - get text of the control
ControlClick - click on the control
etc...
```